# Git - migrate a directory from git repository to another one preserving git history

Tags: git

I was able to follow the steps below, but it seems to collapse the directory.  How can I accomplish without collapsing the directory.

I did everyting in the steps below but imagine the directory structure.

I had files in repo-old:

repo-old/src/main/scala

But it went into new:

repo-new/scala

How do I keep as:

repo-new/src/main/scala

Following the steps below.

https://dev.to/art_ptushkin/how-to-migrate-a-directory-from-git-repository-to-another-one-preserving-git-history-bitbucket-example-15m5

Comment: That tutorial is how to migrate a subset of a repository. If you just want to move your repo without changing the directory structure, see questions about just moving a repo. Note that the answer may be different if you only want to retain a single branch, vs all remote branches.

Comment: I want to move a subset, exactly as described.  I just couldn't see where to have the directory setup exactly as above.

Comment: Oh I see. You want a subset without changing the existing folder structure. The title says that but somehow I missed it.

Comment: I'd recommend using `git-filter-repo` instead of `filter-branch`. It's newer, faster, and has a lot of great [options](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html) for this. You may only need `--path src/main/scala`. See the examples futher down that linked page.

Comment: OK will do, you can add as answer, I will approve